# How to only show errors in the issue navigator?

Tags: xcode

In the issue navigator inside Xcode4, a lot of warnings are shown as well as errors.

How can I force it to only show errors? i.e. I would like hide warnings.

Comment: "I would like hide warnings." - what could possibly go wrong....

Comment: "What could possibly go wrong," indeed. Don't want to see warnings, but want to make sure everything is correct? Try -Werror. :)

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Click the filter button at the bottom of the navigator:

[image]

Comment: I use this all the time usually but it has broken in Xcode 7.3. Hopefully Apple fix in the next version.

Comment: it's working for Xcode 8... is there any keyboard short cut, or any way that I can make errors show on top of warnings in the issue navigator?

Comment: @Josh Caswell is there a keyboard shortcut to accomplish this as well?

Answer (score 13):

at the bottom of navigator filter by **error** word

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In xcode 13 we can click the cross (in blue in the following diagram) to show only errors:
[image]