# Linker Error when updating Xcode to 9.3

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm working with a cross-platform C++ project on Windows and MacOS.
Due to cross-compatibility, I use the flag: `-fshort-wchar` in Xcode to ensure using `2 bytes` instead of `4 bytes` for a wide char as it is on the Windows platform. Now comes the problem.
Using *Xcode 9.2* and below works fine with the flag but after updating to *Xcode 9.3 or 9.4* I get Linker Error.

**LLVM ERROR:**

```
Function Import: link error
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove `-fshort-wchar` it compiles but then I get a runtime error due to using `4 byte` wide chars when the code expects `2 byte`.

`-fshort-wchar` is under Apple *LLVM 9.0* Custom Compiler Flags -> Other C++ Flags

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect this is another "unresolved external symbol" kind of error. Do you link against anything that may use 4-byte wide chars?

Comment: I use fmod, libz and libcurl. How do I know if some of them uses 4 byte wchars? The same lib files works in Xcode 9.2 though.

Comment: Is that the only error? Have you tried checking the buildtime logs for only errors as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039197/how-to-only-show-errors-in-the-issue-navigator I usually find that if there a "linker command failed" there is another error you're not seeing and showing only errors helps.

Comment: No thats the only error