# Android studio: Filtering out only errors in message windows or build windows?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, messagewindow

I have an application which got hundreds of warnings and only few errors during compilation

**(I do not mean  RUNTIME ERROR, or filtering LOGCAT)**.

Are there any methods to only show errors in Messages windows which shows compilation erros or not?
I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2, Intellij Idea.

Comment: The errors will be shown in red and warnings will be shown in yellow

Comment: @Lighteninger I know that but searching by eye for few among hundreds is a boring task!

Comment: @VSB : Under the logcat panner there is a filer to select All/info/error/verbode logs in android studio

Comment: @HardikBambhania Where is that? I can't find any specific filter.

Comment: @HardikBambhania I mean messages Windows (Alt+0) not Logcat(Alt+6)

Comment: I don't know why this question is down voted?!

Comment: Same question is asked here for iOS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18039197/1080355 but gained enough attention and popularity!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In Above image select Error **instead of Verbose**.

Comment: I mean messages Windows (Alt+0) not Logcat(Alt+6)